# Подключение файлов внутри js после сборки

Tags: javascript, electron

Написал приложение на electron, в одной из папок проекта хранятся дополнительные файлы json. Если запускать программу еще до сборки, то все в порядке, а если после сборки, то программа не видит файлы даже через полный путь, и которые вообще хранятся, например, в папке "Документы". Подключаю так

```
const files = require('./assets/files.json');
```

Сборка через electron-packager, windows.

Answer (score 0):

JS по умолчанию не умеет подгружать JSON. Для этого нужно использовать JSON loaders. Например вот этот https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader.

Тогда на момент сборки у тебя в переменную `files` загрузится JSON.

Соответственно после сборки ты уже не подгрузишь свой JSON. Для этого нужно использовать AJAX.